# MySQL left outer join issue double id

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using a left outer join in a query. but now I'm getting a double id,
What I mean is that I now get the id of table 1 and the id of table2 both called id.

Is there a way to maybe rename(prefix) the id of table 2 with something like 
table2_id? without having to use 'AS table_nameOfColumn' for every column of table 2

My current query:

```
SELECT invoices.*, clients.* FROM invoices 
LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON invoices.employee_id = users.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN clients ON users.client_id = clients.id
WHERE invoices.employee_id = 3
```

Comment: your only option is to use `as`: sql is returning the columns it finds as you defined them, if you want to use a different column name, you'll need to use as.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply add  an alias to your columns name naming explicitally

eg:

```
  SELECT invoices.id as invoce_id, clients.id as client_id FROM invoices 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON invoices.employee_id = users.id 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN clients ON users.client_id = clients.id
  WHERE invoices.employee_id = 3
```

Comment: Thanks guess that will do just fine for now. 
I suppose you have use AS for every column with the same name?

Comment: yep. do avoid disambiguation. Or you can, alternatively use full name, incl. table name (`table.column`)